# ajax page redirection 405 error

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

New to ajax and sorry for asking such a basic question. I am using `ajax`:

1. to submit a form (written in python)
2. to conduct some calculation and generate output page, and
3. to redirect the browser to the output page

Currently, Steps 1 and 2 are done, but when the browser tries to redirect, I got a `405 error`. I appreciate any suggestions.

#### HTML form

```
<form method="post" id="form1">File to upload:
    <input type="file" id="upfile1" name="upfile" class="required input_button" accept=".csv" />
    <input class="submit_button" type="button" value="Submit" />Upload the file!
</form>
```

#### JS code

```
$('.submit_button').click(function () {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    $.each($('input[name^="upfile"]')[0].files, function (i, file) {
        form_data.append('file-' + i, file);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/geneec_batchoutput.html", ///////NOTE 1/////////
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            window.location = '/geneec_batchoutput.html'; ///////NOTE 2/////////
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        }

    });
});
```

#### NOTE 1

Form `firebug`, I can tell the calculations have been finished and the output page is generated.[image] [image]

#### NOTE 2

Here is the place I got `405 error`. So my guess is `ajax` did not redirect the browser to the "correct" output page, instead it let the browser go to a generic one. So without data support, I got `405 error`.

So it seems like my question is how to redirect the browser to the output page generated in `###note 1` at location `###note 2`.

### update

I have attached a "working" scenario, but this is not the real `ajax` approach, since I use .submit() to send the form.

#### html form

```
<form method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=geneec_batchoutput.html>File to upload:
    <input type="file" id="upfile1" name="upfile" class="required input_button" accept=".csv" />
    <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" />Upload the file!
</form>
```

#### JS code

```
   form.submit();
   $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "/geneec_batchoutput.html",

       success: function () {
           window.location = '/geneec_batchoutput.html';
       }
   });
```

#### Update 2

I tried to check the content of `url` by posting it to the console. It looks like the `url` has everything I need, which is the output page. So temporally I use `$("body").html(url);` to replace current page content. But the url is still the `/geneec_batchinput.html`. Is there a way to update the url as well?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/geneec_batchoutput.html",
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                console.log(url)
                $("body").html(url);
                },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error')
                }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed: 
`A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource; for example, using GET on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code#4xx_Client_Error - What happens if you go to that page directly in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `location` redirect is getting called as a `POST` request because it's inside the `submit` action.  Try tweaking your submit handler like so:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // carry on...
```

so that you can use [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to avoid needing to return something from the submit event.

### Update:

This may be it. Using your original code:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // .. blah blah ..
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/geneec_batchoutput.html", ///////NOTE 1/////////
        // .. blah blah ..
        success: function () {
            window.location = '/geneec_batchoutput.html'; ///////NOTE 2/////////
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
    retun false;
});
```

Because it's asynchronous, the outer event handler is ending before the location change is issued in the success callback function. I thought the preventDefault would avoid the need to return false, but other similar questions suggest not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not stop the `405 error`. I have attached another screenshot in the post with the http headers for your information. I am wondering whether or not my approach is reasonable. In addition, I have attached a working scenario, but it is not the real `ajax` approach, since I use .submit() to submit the form.

Comment: Try returning false in the outer event handler after the ajax function. see update

Comment: After adding the `return false;` it seems like the page did nothing after hitting the `submit` button. No jobs or output page were created (at location `###note 1`)....